# Iteratively name output files in a loop while using arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass

Tags: arcpy, feature-class, string, for-loop

I have four input feature classes and one feature dataset which I am trying to send them to. I would like the new feature classes to have the same names as the originals. My process is as follows:

```
for file in working_files: 
    arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(file,sesc_fd, r"C:\Users\delenteny\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Dale_Workspace\Dale_Workspace.gdb\%file%")
```

I receive an error when running the code as above which says

> The name contains invalid characters. Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).

Comment: `arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(file,sesc_fd, os.path.basename(file))` but don't forget to `import os` first.

Comment: Your used raw formatting, not `f`, so the variable was not applied

Comment: An `f` wouldn't matter, that wouldn't be a valid f-string anyway.

Comment: And the 3rd parameter is a dataset "name*, not a full path.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for file in working_files:
    output_location = "C:\\Users\\delenteny\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Projects\\Dale_Workspace\\Dale_Workspace.gdb\\" + file
    arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(file, sesc_fd, output_location)
```

Comment: Instead of string math, use `os.path.join`

Comment: And the first three parameters are `in_features`,`out_path`, and `out_name`, so the usage is wrong.